# How to get all the vault team members in Tales from the Borderlands?

Tags: tales-from-the-borderlands

My team consisted of additonal three members:

- Cassius

  > because I stopped Athena from killing him
- Athena
- August

Yet it is shown that there could have been more.

How do I get the possibility to recruit them all?

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out on [telltale's forum](http://www.telltalegames.com/community/discussion/101000/getting-team-members-ep5-spoilers):

> - Cassius
>
>   - Tell Athena to spare Cassius
> - Springs
>
>   - Honor Scooter OR
>   - Do not cover for Athena in Episode 2
>   - Do not lie about the mission in Episode 4
> - Mystery Vault Hunter
>
>   - Have 4300 dollars or more
> - Zer0
>
>   - Tell Mordecai that you are a vault hunter OR
>   - Tell Athena that you like vault hunting
> - Felix
>
>   - Warn him about the bomb
> - August
>
>   - Don't blame him in Episode 1

Athena is available by default.

Comment: Your link shows a slightly different note for August (i.e. it says this character is also available be default).

Comment: @camelCase I think this was based on my own experience when I locked out August due to blaming him.